# Keyboard opens up automatically on setState()

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am building a mobile application using flutter. The app has a homepage with an AnimatedIndexedStack. To switch to another screen I simply change the index. If I run the app,  I can switch to any screen without any problem. However, if I switch to a screen with a textfield and tap on the textfield to edit. Now after cancelling the keyboard, if I switch to any other screen, the keyboard pops up automatically when there are no textfields on the screens and I am not tapping on any textfield. Regardless of the start screen and the end screen, the keyboard pops up automatically after changing the index.

The animated indexed stack looks like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AnimatedIndexedStack extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;
  final List<Widget> children;

  const AnimatedIndexedStack({
    Key? key,
    required this.index,
    required this.children,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AnimatedIndexedStackState createState() => _AnimatedIndexedStackState();
}

class _AnimatedIndexedStackState extends State<AnimatedIndexedStack>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _controller;
  late Animation<double> _animation;
  int _index = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
    );
    _animation = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(

      CurvedAnimation(
        parent: _controller,
        curve: Curves.ease,
      ),
    );

    _index = widget.index;
    _controller.forward();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(AnimatedIndexedStack oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    if (widget.index != _index) {
      _controller.reverse().then((_) {
        setState(() => _index = widget.index);
        _controller.forward();
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _animation,
      builder: (context, child) {
        return Opacity(
          opacity: _controller.value,
          child: child,
        );
      },
      child: IndexedStack(
        index: _index,
        children: widget.children,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

homepage looks like this:

```
class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {

  const Homepage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomepageState createState() => _HomepageState();
}

class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {

  
  var _currentIndex = 0;
  final _homeIndex = 0;
  final _titles = ['Home', 'New Booking', 'Trips', 'Payment History', 'Support', 'Profile'];
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  var _bookingStep = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _currentIndex = _homeIndex;

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => _onWillPop(),
      child: Scaffold(
        key: scaffoldKey,
        extendBody: true,
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,

        drawer: AppDrawer(selectedIndex: _currentIndex, onItemTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _currentIndex = index;
          });
          scaffoldKey.currentState!.closeDrawer();
        },),
   

        body: SafeArea(
          bottom: false,
          child: AnimatedIndexedStack(
            index: _currentIndex,
            children: [
              const BookingsScreen(),
              NewBookingScreen(onExit: () {
                setState(() {
                  _currentIndex = 0;
                });
              }, bookingStep: _bookingStep, nextStep: () {
                setState(() {
                  _bookingStep = _bookingStep + 1;
                });
              },),
              const Trips(),
              const PaymentHistoryScreen(),
              SupportScreen(),
              const ProfileScreen()
            ],
          )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to all screens where you have the issue,

```
FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it didn't solve the problem.